# Finding maximum number from a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to find maximum number from a loop and it's number of occurrences. Here is the code I have written so far.

```
public class MaxNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int count_max = 0;
        while (true) {
             number = input.nextInt();
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }
            number = max;
            if (max > number) {
                max=number;
                count_max++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Max Number: " + number);
        System.out.println("Occurences: " + count_max);
    }
```

I getting only zero in the output, any logical error I am making?

Comment: you are breaking the loop if the number == 0 maybe you never make an iteration check the value of `input.nextInt()`, your `while` statement looks infinite I have a feeling the compiler makes some weird optimizations around this, your logic of obtaining the maximum number (highest number?) is questionable

Comment: If this is a homework question, then please tag it as such. :)

Comment: if the code examples below don't work, print the variable `number` or use the debugger to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my version of what I think you are trying to achieve, it is mostly working, please note that you have to start typing in numbers if you start with a string it fails  as you describe, also note numbers larger then `long` get ignored or 'trimmed'

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;

        System.out.println("Type some numbers!");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner ln = new Scanner(in);

        while (ln.hasNextLong()) {
            a = ln.nextLong();
            if (a > b) {
                b = a;
                ++d;
            }
            ++c;
        }

        System.out.println("\n   info:");
        System.out.println("     highest:" + b);
        System.out.println("     iterations:" + c);
        System.out.println("     overrides:" + d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you have the line:

```
number = max
```

followed by

```
if (max > number) {
```

max will never be greater than number since you just set them to be equal in the preceding line

Answer (score 0):

remove the line `number = max`

Comment: if (max > number) is also wrong.. max starts off as 0.. and is only reassigned if its greater than number.. it won't be unless number is negative.. try if (number > max) instead

Comment: But still maximum number comes as 0 and occurrences come as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems with the code.  This should work for you:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int number = 0;
        int count_max = 0;
        while (true) {
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if(max == number){
                count_max++;
            }
            if (max < number) {
                max=number;
                count_max = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Max Number: " + max);
        System.out.println("Occurences: " + count_max);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the line you have with "number = max" needs to be modified. The code you have there is setting the value of number to the value of max every time through the loop. Since this has the value of 0 the first time through the loop, it will just keep on being zero indefinitely. That means that your max never changes.

So you don't want that line, but you do want something like it. *If* the number *has the same value* as (==) max, *then* you need to add 1 to count_max.

The last If block needs a slight tweak too. *If* you find a new highest value (ie, *number > max*, not the other way around), *then* you need to **reset** your count_max to 1, not add 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a corrected version of the code with the mistakes you made highlighted.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int max = 0;
int number = 0;
int count_max = 0;
while (true) {
    number = input.nextInt();
    if (number == 0) {
        break;
    }
    // you are assigning number = max, and max is 0 initially, so number
    // =0;
    // number =max;
    // if number =0 and max =0 then below condition will never          // satisfied.
    if (max < number) {
        max = number;
        // it means every time when you have any number greater then the                // second one just add it.
            // count_max++;
            count_max = 0;
        }

    // This condition will make sure that only add count by 1 if max =
    // currentNum
    if (max == number) {

        count_max++;
    }

}
// You have written number instead of max down there.
System.out.println("Max Number: " + max);
System.out.println("Occurences: " + count_max);
```